# How to remove all inline styled `style=properties+val` from every tag from a long source code?

Tags: css

How to remove all inline styled `style=properties+val` from every tag from a long source code quickly.

For example.

```
<p style="border:2px red solid">some text</p>
<span style="background:red">some text</span>
```

to

```
<p>some text</p>
<span>some text</span>
```

Comment: Programmatically or manually?

Comment: Manually. i just want to remove it quickly because after that i will wrote css in external style sheet. code is very long and randomly styled css in style tag.IF i will go to one by one then it will take huge time and i can't use Find and replace because properties and valuesare different for many tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your editor supports regular expression find and replace (and if it doesn't, get a new editor):

Find with this regular expression: `\s?style="[^"]*"`

Replace with: nothing!

Note that this will not catch instances where your code is malformed, as shown in your example (missing double quote at the end of the first style).

Comment: +1 Obviously a case for regular expressions. It is amazing how many people do not have a basic grasp of regular expressions and how/when to apply them. Not bagging on the OP, just sayin... Rx should be required reading...